# Splitting a sentence without any whitespace/seperators into a sentence with whitespace

Tags: prolog, tokenize

I'm working on an end-of-semester project for a Programming languages course. The assignment is given below. I'm finishing writing it in Java and I'm having a lot of trouble writing in Prolog. I've been having a lot of trouble with Prolog so this question is as much looking for help with the assignment as it is trying to understand Prolog more. Any help that I can get would be GREATLY appreciated

> A sentence contains words, all
>   occurring in a dictionary, that happen
>   to be concatenated without white
>   spaces as separators. Describe a
>   solution that produces all possible
>   answers, compatible with a given
>   dictionary in 2 out of the following 
>   3 languages: Java, Haskell, Prolog. The
>   test data is provided as a UTF-8 text
>   file containing one sentence per line,
>   with all words occurring in the
>   dictionary, provided as a UTF-8 text
>   file with one word on each line. The
>   output should be a UTF-8 text file
>   containing the sentences with all
>   words separated by white spaces.
>
> Example of word file:
>
> cat
>   dog
>   barks
>   runs
>   the
>   away
>
> an example of sentence file is
>
> thedogbarks
>   thecatrunsaway

Comment: Could you ask a specific question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know where to even start with it, honestly

Comment: What's the behavior when words are prefixes of others, i.e. both "the" and "there" are words?

Comment: when it's writing the sentences with spaces to the file, it needs to show all possibilities

Answer (score 3):

The core of your program should be a predicate that tokenizes a list of character codes, i.e. builds a list of atoms (= words) out of the codes. Below is an outline:

```
%% tokenize(+Codes:list, -Atoms:list)
%
% Converts a list of character codes
% into a list of atoms. There can be several solutions.
tokenize([], []) :- !.

tokenize(Cs, [A | As]) :-
    % Use append/3 to extract the Prefix of the code list
    append(...),
    % Check if the prefix constitutes a word in the dictionary,
    % and convert it into an atom.
    is_word(Prefix, A),
    % Parse the remaining codes
    tokenize(...).
```

You can now define:

```
is_word(Codes, Atom) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
    word(Atom).

word(the).
word(there).
word(review).
word(view).

split_words(Sentence, Words) :-
    atom_codes(Sentence, Codes),
    tokenize(Codes, Words).
```

and use it like this:

```
?- split_words('thereview', Ws).
Ws = [the, review] ;
Ws = [there, view] ;
false.
```

or use it in something more complex where you parse a file to obtain the input and output the results into a file.

Comment: +1. If the OP wants extra credit, they should give a dynamic programming solution in Prolog ;)