# Couldn't match expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a total Haskell noob and I was hoping someone could help me with this because I've been at this for hours and I just know that I'm doing something ridiculously stupid.

The program is supposed to scan a dictionary file to determine all valid word sequences for a collection of sentences with spaces removed.

Ex. "insidewaysoften" could be broken down to "in side ways often", "inside way soften", etc.

I wrote my prototype in python and it works just fine (as does my Java implementation), but the course requires a Haskell implementation and I cannot get it to work. Apologies in advance for the crimes I have committed against the language and GHC with the following code:

```
import System.Environment   

main = do
  [dictFilename,sentFilename] <- getArgs  
  dictFile <- readFile dictFilename
  sentFile <- readFile sentFilename

  mapM (\sentence -> solve "" "" sentence (words dictFile)) (words sentFile)

solve prefix header [] dict =
  if (header `elem` dict) 
  then return prefix ++ header
  else return ""

solve prefix header sent dict = do
  let more = solve prefix (header ++ (take 1 sent)) (drop 1 sent) dict

  if (header `elem` dict) 
  then return (solve (prefix ++ header ++ " ") "" sent dict) ++ more
  else return more
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it? What error do you get? Where?

Comment: Are you by chance taking the same course as MeeksMan13, who wrote [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852841/splitting-a-sentence-without-any-whitespace-seperators-into-a-sentence-with-white)? Also, yeah, does this produce an error, or is it just not working correctly? And if so, in what way is it failing?

Comment: Yes, Jeffrey, it does seem I am in the same course as MeeksMan13. I saw his question right after I had posted mine.  The code I posted was returning type errors like Rotsor demonstrated in his post, and I think I will be fine based on the information he provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing when investigating type errors is to write down the type signatures of functions you know.

Here, solve may have type

```
solve :: String -> String -> String -> [String] -> String
```

or

```
solve :: String -> String -> String -> [String] -> IO String
```

Depending on whether it should have any side-effects while computing the value. Seeing you using `mapM` and `return` all over the place, I guess the `IO` version may have been intended.

Now, if you write down the signature, you start getting much more meaningful error messages. For example, instead of this:

```
tmp.hs:19:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: [Char]
      Actual type: [[Char]]
    In the return type of a call of `solve'
    In the first argument of `return', namely
      `(solve (prefix ++ header ++ " ") "" sent dict)'
```

, which does not make much sense, you get this:

```
tmp.hs:14:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO String' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the expression: return prefix ++ header
    In the expression:
      if (header `elem` dict) then return prefix ++ header else return ""
    In an equation for `solve':
        solve prefix header [] dict
          = if (header `elem` dict) then
                  return prefix ++ header
            else
                return ""
```

,which shows exactly where the problem is. Function application has the highest priority in Haskell, so `return prefix ++ header` is equivalent to `(return prefix) ++ header`, which is definitely not what you meant.

By the way, if I remove `IO` from the return type, remove all the `return`s and change the invocation by adding `putStrLn`, the code compiles and works! The only problem is that it concatenates all the possible sentences together into a single string without any delimiting.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the sort of reply I had been hoping for. :)